# Trailing characters in VIM editor

Tags: vim

```
vim demo.text
Error detected while processing /home/ftdetect/less.vim:
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
Error detected while processing /home/ftdetect/sinatra.vim:
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: ^M
line    3:
E488: Trailing characters
Error detected while processing /home/plugin/ScreenShot.vim:
line   94:
E488: Trailing characters
line  105:
E488: Trailing characters
```

This is the error I am getting when I am opening vim editor

Comment: What is the output of `cat --show-all` of one of the offending files?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902754/vim-startup-errors-invalid-expression-debian

Answer (score 1):

probably you tried getting those files from Windows. Try running

```
dos2unix demo.text demo.text
```

Comment: still I am getting the same error dude..

Comment: Did you tried importing other .vim files as well from windows onto *nix system

Comment: No I have not imported any file I downloaded and installed vim from these site as ubuntu type from https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles and my Operating system is Ubuntu

Comment: did you run dos2unix command? can you paste the output of cat -v demo.txt?

Comment: sudo apt-get install dos2unix
Reading package lists... Done After my installation I have done  l# dos2unix /etc/vim/vimrc /etc/vim/vimrc
dos2unix: converting file /etc/vim/vimrc to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file /etc/vim/vimrc to Unix format ...

Comment: and what does cat gives you?

Comment: This is the output I got it ...cat /etc/vim/vimrc
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim and sourced by
" the call to :runtime you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those
" settings, you should do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim
" will be overwritten everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.
" It is recommended to make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters
" the value of the 'compatible' option.